# Multi-tenant Heroku app with SSL + GoDaddy SSL on custom domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, multi-tenant

I have a multi-tenant Heroku app running Ruby on Rails with a wildcard SSL certificate on *.xyz.com which serves https://customer1-app.xyz.com securely & as expected. The problem is I can't add a GoDaddy SSL certificate to a custom domain (customer1.com) also at Godaddy pointing to one of the subdomains (customer1-app.xyz.com).

The approach I'm trying is fully described at here: https://help.heroku.com/8P5TVA4T/how-can-i-configure-multiple-ssl-certificates-for-a-single-app

Simply put:

1. I created a shell application customer1-endpoint on Heroku
2. I added the SSL-Endpoint addon & installed the certificated bought
   from GoDaddy on the shell application
3. I copied the endpoint (DNS target - abc.ssl.herokudns.com) from the Heroku CLI to theCNAME
   record of GoDaddy
4. I added the custom domain (customer1.com, [www.customer1.com](http://www.customer1.com)) to my main production (xyz.com)
   Heroku app

When I try to access https://www.customer1.com/ I receive a "No such app" message on Heroku.
Any ideas what's going on wrong?

Comment: Would you mind just pasting the contents of your help.heroku.com link into the question directly and perhaps skip the summary? If the link goes dead we're all in trouble...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming through Google, my issue was that I had my SSL-endpoint in a different region than my main app. This approach works, make sure that both apps are on the same region.

Answer (score 0):

SSL Endpoint is deprecated as of July 31st, 2021.